# Could not resolve symbols with new gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build-tools

One of my old project was working great with gradle `2.1.2` and build tool version `25` since i update gradle to `3.1.3` and build tool to 28 i have got problem with libraries,
everything ok and my project run without error, but on android studio it shows lots of error where i used library, error messages are starts with `Could not resolve...`

with those errors my project work like before, but android studio doesn't show me any suggestion

**What i do**
remove completely `build tools 28` and install `27` but doesn't work

what should i do to fix this problem?

[image: project work with this error!]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`
 into
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'` from your project level **gradle.build** Like the image below, and then resync your project!
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you not added library for SpaceNavigationView in Gradle file, android studio can not find a file and gives you a error. you need to add following library in your app gradle.

```
compile 'com.github.armcha:SpaceNavigationView:1.6.0'
```